# Globally installed anchor version is not correct

Tags: anchor, anchor-test

Getting an issue trying to run `anchor test`. How do I update my globally installed anchor?

Error: `Globally installed anchor version is not correct. Expected "anchor-cli 0.24.2", found "anchor-cli 0.25.0".`

I have tried `avm use latest` and still get the error.

Answer (score 3):

I uninstalled my old anchor binary. There were a couple of steps I tried first:

`npm uninstall anchor-cli`

This would work if I install via npm. I did not.

`cargo uninstall anchor`

This would work if I installed with cargo. I did not.

**Solution**: I found the binary and got rid of it

```
$ which anchor
/opt/homebrew/bin/anchor
$ rm /opt/homebrew/bin/anchor
$ anchor --version
anchor-cli 0.25.0
```